# Kubernetes Nginx-Ingress WebSocket issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I migrated my cluster system to Kubernetes. But I am having problems with websocket. I was using normal nginx reverse proxy in my Bare Metal cluster system, but I could not run it with the following configuration. How should I go about configuring a standard nginx reverse proxy on the kubernetes side? Isn't the default nginx-ingress enough?

Nginx-Ingress : `helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: production-server
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.org/lb-method: "ip_hash"
    nginx.org/proxy-connect-timeout: "10s"
    nginx.org/proxy-read-timeout: "10s"
    nginx.org/proxy-send-timeout: "10s"
    nginx.org/websocket-services: "production-server"


spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: production-server
            port:
              number: 8000

  tls:
  - secretName: production-cert
    hosts:
      - test.example.com
```

Comment: You say you could not run it with the following configuration, but you don't say why. I can't see the way to help you without any info about the problem you're having.